# Get latest date in a column based on a duplicate value in a table using Powerautomate

Tags: azure-logic-apps, powerapps, power-automate

I have a table in dataverse, that has a date, telephone number, and ID columns as below.

| Date | ID | Telnum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/6/202 | abcd | 8421678 |
| 12/9/2020 | abce | 8421679 |
| 12/13/2020 | abcg | 8421678 |

From the table the 1st and 3rd column have the same Tel num, but different dates and ID. What am trying to achieve is on the same table in a column called end date,post the last date with regards to the tel num this is basically the 1st date of the date the number switched to a new record based on ID.
The table am trying to come up with looks as below

| Date | ID | Telnum | Date To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/6/202 | abcd | 8421678 | 12/13/2020 |
| 12/9/2020 | abce | 8421679 |  |
| 12/13/2020 | abcg | 8421678 |  |

What I've tried is create an Instant flow, List Records(The table name), List records 2 (Table name but this tome with filters {The filters are (tel num eq tel num and id ne id)}, Then Update record to populate the end date.
What am missing is a step to get the max or latest date of the column that I will append to the date to mapping.
Any idea on how to achieve this will be highly appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: Hi Didi, may I know if my answer helps your problem ? If I misunderstood your requirement, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, any update ?

Comment: Hi Hury, tahanks for your comment,

For distinguishing the two records, is it not possible to use the id.

Comment: Hi Didi, I'm a little confused about your requirement. In your original question, you asked about how to get the latest date, but in your comment you aked `is it not possible to use the id`. Could you please describe your question detaily ? In my opinion, you can just distinguish the two records by id(if the id is unique) and do not need to create another column with date.

Comment: Oh it's because I will use the date range to link it up to another table, that is where tel are the same but date ranges are different.

Comment: So does the solution below meet your requirement ? If not, please provide more details of your requirement, I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of your requirement, it seems you want to add one more column(named `Date To`) for the table and set the current date(you mentioned as max or latest date) as the value of the new column.

The second table you provide shows the value of `DateTo` should be like `12/13/2020`, but if you just set the date with the format `month/day/year`, it can't help you distinguish the two records which has same `Telnum` because they are both `12/13/2020`. So you should set the value of `DateTo` with format of `2020-12-21T07:23:34.5951356Z`. To implement it, you can use `utcNow()` method shown like below screenshot.
[image]

If I misunderstand your requirement, please let me know and provide more details about your question.